# Creating a soft link

Tags: linux, permissions, non-root-user

I'm trying to create a soft link for a file but keep getting a permission denied message. I don't want to create it under the root user but a different user I have created. This user has rwx permissions for the file and I'm wondering what else I could be missing to have permission denied. The command I'm using is

```
ln -s /home/MarxBros/marx1.txt /marx1.lnk
```

The user has rwx for marx1.txt and the /home/MarxBros directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax that you are using:

```
ln -s /home/MarxBros/marx1.txt /marx1.lnk
```

is attempting to create the directory in `/` as in `/mark1.ink`.

That isn't going to work because only root has write access to `/` as you can verify with `ls -ld /`

In order for what you are doing to work, you need to create the link in a location in which the user has modify access.

Comment: This 100% solved the problem. I've only had practice creating soft links in the root directory. As a basic user, what would an example of syntax for a hard link be?

Comment: Creating a hard link is just like creating a softlink but without the `-s` flag.

Comment: Oh, and if this 100% solved your problem, you should accept it as correct.